# Array lengths differed error showing while returning Array<Int> in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
fun countPositivesSumNegatives(input : Array<Int>?) : Array<Int> {
  //code here
   
    var sum = 0
    var negativeSum=0
   
     if(input!=null){
         for (i in input){
        if(i>0){
            sum = sum+1
        } 
        else {
            negativeSum+=i
    }
     }
         
         }
     
   return arrayOf(sum,negativeSum)
    
    
       }
```

I have to return the array of two elements, one is count of positive integers and another is sum of negative integers.
For an example testcase it passed. But for random testcase it is showing error as ' Array length differed, expected.length = 0 but actual.length = 2 ' I am attaching screenshot of error. Please help me to find out the error and proper methodology to solve it.[image]

Comment: Maybe it expects a zero-length array when the input array is null.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without knowing what the tests are.  But while your code always returns a two-element array, the test clearly expects an empty array in some circumstances.  So either the test is wrong, or your code is wrong.  As Tenfour04 says, the most obvious circumstance where you might expect an empty array is where the input is null; other possible circumstances might include an empty input array, or just possibly where all its elements are zero.

Comment: PS. Is the line `sum = sum+1` right?  That'll give the _count_ of positive elements, not their sum.  (That doesn't explain your test failure, though.)  PPS. If you want a much simpler and shorter function, you might want to look at the [`filter()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) and [`sum()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) functions.

Comment: @gidds Yep it was asking in case of empty array. Used filter, sum and check if isEmptyOrNull() to optimise the solution. It worked. Thanks